# Merge several excel workbooks into one sheet into new columns

Tags: vba, excel-2010

i need to merge multiple excel workbooks into a single sheet..i found the below coding but it merges the sheets into rows. Please help me to consolidate the workbook to columns in a single sheet

For example i have two workbooks with below columns:

[image]

[image]

I need to consolidate them to a single sheet as below:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportCSV()

    Dim strSourcePath As String
    Dim strDestPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strData As String
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim Cnt As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Change the path to the source folder accordingly
    strSourcePath = "C:\Path\"

    If Right(strSourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then strSourcePath = strSourcePath & "\"

    'Change the path to the destination folder accordingly
    strDestPath = "C:\Path\"

    If Right(strDestPath, 1) <> "\" Then strDestPath = strDestPath & "\"

    strFile = Dir(strSourcePath & "*.csv")

    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        Cnt = Cnt + 1
        r = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Open strSourcePath & strFile For Input As #1
            Do Until EOF(1)
                Line Input #1, strData
                x = Split(strData, ",")
                For c = 0 To UBound(x)
                    Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Trim(x(c))
                Next c
                r = r + 1
            Loop
        Close #1
        Name strSourcePath & strFile As strDestPath & strFile
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If Cnt = 0 Then _
        MsgBox "No CSV files were found...", vbExclamation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The bit to change is right here:

```
r = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Open strSourcePath & strFile For Input As #1
     Do Until EOF(1)
         Line Input #1, strData
         x = Split(strData, ",")
         For c = 0 To UBound(x)
             Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Trim(x(c))
         Next c
         r = r + 1
     Loop
```

r here is refering to Rows.. and its value stays the same over the loop.
c on the other hand is used as a ways of specifying which column in a row to put a value from x.

Simply swap these references over.
Something like:

```
c = Cells(Cols.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Col + 1
Open strSourcePath & strFile For Input As #1
     Do Until EOF(1)
         Line Input #1, strData
         x = Split(strData, ",")
         For r = 0 To UBound(x)
             Cells(r, c).Value = Trim(x(r))
         Next r
         c = c + 1
     Loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But this doesnt provide me the correct output. I too tried this before. What i need to do is identify the end of columns in the new file and add it to "c". But i do not know how to identify the number of columns in the merged file. Please help

Comment: ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)

This cell is the last cell in your worksheet... its column is the last used column. Does that help?